# Use Python to extract paragraph that has highlighted word in PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation

My goal is to have a list of `terms` and to iterate through them and when occurrences are found, to highlight them in an output PDF document. This currently works using the code below:

```
# The list of files to iterate over
fileList = ["test"]

def runForFile(f):
    # Read in the PDF
    print(f"Opening file {f}.pdf...")
    doc = fitz.open(f"inputs\\{f}.pdf")
    
    term_count = defaultdict(int)
    term_paragraphs = defaultdict(list)
    
    for term in terms2:
        print(f"Searching for {term}")
        for page in tqdm(doc):
            # Search for the term on the page
            text_instances = page.search_for(term)
            # Highlight the term for each occurrence
            for inst in text_instances:
                page.add_highlight_annot(inst).update()
                # Count the occurrence of the term and store the surrounding text
                term_count[term] += 1
                paragraph = page.get_text("text", clip=inst).strip()
                term_paragraphs[term].append((page.number, paragraph))

    # Create a new document with the highlights 
    doc.save(f"outputs\\{f}-output.pdf")
```

However, now I want to create a new output document that takes the paragraph the highlighted word was contained within and outputs it into the document. This way, only paragraphs where the highlighted words occur will be extracted and not include superfluous paragraphs. I have tried doing this with the following:

```
# Create a new document with the paragraphs where the highlighted words appear
    for term, paragraphs in term_paragraphs.items():
        new_doc = fitz.open()
        for page_num, paragraph in paragraphs:
            
            new_page = new_doc.new_page()
            new_page.insert_text((10, 10), f"Page {page_num}: {paragraph}")
            # find the coordinates of the newly added text
            text_area = fitz.Rect(10, 10, 500, 500) # adjust as needed
            text_area = new_page.search_for(paragraph, hit_max=1)[0]
            # crop the page to the text area and update the page
            new_page.crop(text_area)
            new_page.update()
        new_doc.save(f"{term}-paragraphs.pdf")
```

The problem I am having is that the file is not being created at all. I have tried changing the indentation of `new_doc.save`, but that is not having an effect. Can anyone spot my issue?